# Identify these Cold War speeches from a movie trailer

Tags: cold-war, john-f-kennedy

I've recently seen [a movie trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_Ky4KPzKwY&t=1m02s) that contains 2 speeches of president John F. Kennedy and one speech of Khrushchev.

Could anyone provide the links of the original speeches?

EDIT: Since some people hear "only" one speech, there is FOOTAGE of two more speeches, but there is no audio,  They are both shown on the CGI'd newspaper. It is overlapped by Kennedy's "Commencement address 1963" (Thanks to Mark C. Wallace for already finding this one!)

[image]

Comment: I only heard one speech from Kennedy in that trailer.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I'm not sure how possible it is to identify a speech merely from a few frames of the image of someone speaking. Even assuming it's actually taken from real footage and not computer animated like the rest of the scene, it's a pretty tall order.

Comment: I didn't see footage of any other speeches there either. Perhaps Youtube is showing different trailers in different regions via the same URL?

Comment: If someone could get a freeze frame of the newspaper, it would go a long way to finding the speeches.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I added a screenshot of what I believed to be the scene.

Comment: The graphic isn't clear enough to read the titles of the speeches, but the masthead **The National Status** returns no results in a google search. It is possible that they aren't referring to two specific speeches, but to the general conflict.

Answer (score 2):

If you type the first five words of the speech into a search engine, the answer is easy to find.  [Commencement address 1963](http://www1.american.edu/media/speeches/Kennedy.htm)